# how to programmatically enter the number into phone application screen in android during conversation

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to programmatically enter the number into phone application of android phone during conversation by my android program. (like this actions - 1.open dial keypad and 2.typing the number).

For example - when you call the phone number and this phone number has extension phone number for calling to the destination. For eg - (ph no - +6581329445 and ext no - 303) So, firstly you will need to call the phone number(eg - +6581329445 ) and then you will need to press the desire extension no (eg - 303) after picked up the phone by other side(callee).

I would like to do this step by programmatically. Now, I can call to the phone number(eg - +6581329445) from my program and then the callee will picked the phon, after that I will need to put the number of destination extension number(eg - 303) from my program for calling to target destination extension.(likely to dial the destination extension number(eg - 303) in keypad of phone application answering screen during the callee(eg - +6581329445) answering the phone).

Use cases explanation by pictures.

Call to hotel phone no (eg - +6581329445)

[image]

Enter the room extension no (eg - 303)

[image]

I would like to do step 2 from my program. Is it possible? If it is possible, please give me advice and how to code this step in android programming. Many thanks.

Comment: I recommend spending a little time in the Android API, if I recall, there are some methods that can do virtually all that easily and predefined http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite so sure adding the extension might be possible, can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do? I'm a bit confused..

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper, I don't think you know the API as well as you think you do. You can't send DTMF after a call is in progress. However, you could send a pause and extension in the dialing string, like `6581329445,,303`.

Comment: @323go You're right, I tried to correct my mistake with my second comment. I had trouble understanding the OP the first time so I misread the question. I thought he was just trying to enter a number onto the screen

Comment: Thanks for all comments but I still need to understand more on it. I would like to explain more about my case. In our country, some building has phone number and some extension phone numbers for each room in this building. When you call to the building phone, the automatic operator will answer you and tell you for press to extension number of target room(specific room). I would like to do these step from my program, call to building phone no and then put the extension phone no of my target destination room by programmatically. Thanks.

Comment: @323go 6581329445,,33 does not work for me

Answer (score 4):

As you know you can ask Android dial a number for you:

```
   Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + numberString);
   Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
   startActivity(dial);
```

But on stock Android, you cannot **interact** with the dialer application after you have dialled your number.

---

However, you can tell the dialer to set a **pause** between some numbers:

- either a 2-second pause,
- or an indefinite wait.

To enter a 2-second pause between numbers, use a "," in the dial string:

- "6581329445,303" (thanks to @323go)

To wait indefinitely, use a ";" in the dial string:

- "6581329445;123"

This can be more useful in some situations - it depends on how long the automated answering service will take to allow you to enter the extension.

The indefinite pause is handled by the dialer by popping up a dialog in the dialler app, allowing the user to send the extra numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to @DreadHeadedDeveloper's comment, I can use dial string(6581329445,,303) for sending pause and extension no. Thanks.

Comment: @Kyaw According to user 323go, you mean. Thanks for the tip - I looked further into it, and using a ";" might be more useful to you, depending on the speed of the automated answer service.