# Add 2-sec pause in phone call android

Tags: android

I would like to add 2-sec pause in android phone call. Here is the code that I am using:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);          
        i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:15000,4");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.call_number)));
```

However this only dial 15000, not 15000,4.

Here is what I actually like to achive :

[image]

Comment: 2-sec pause in a phone call? what do you mean?

Comment: use countdowntimer of 2sec and inside it put ur following code

Comment: @AmitRanjan you did not get it.

Comment: Have you checked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520263/how-to-programmatically-enter-the-number-into-phone-application-screen-in-androi) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android supports pauses in phone numbers - both non-interactive ~2 secs `pause` (code `,`) and interactive `wait` triggered with code `;`.  Aside from syntax error in your code that makes it non compilable at the moment, it all looks fine and shall work once syntax is corrected.

You are probably fooled here by the fact that dialer will display `15000` only when dialing - and that's fine because this is the number you want it to call. All the other digits should be **send**, but these are **not** part of the number. Also note that connection to `15000` must be established first (so someone/something needs to pick up) otherwise nothing would happen. But that's it quite logical.

**EDIT**

Note that **dialer** that will be handling this request may i.e. strip or ommit the sequence. Most I've checked do so. The solution is to bypass dialer completely by using `ACTION_CALL` instead of `ACTION_DIAL`. The downide is that that you require `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` permission for `ACTION_CALL`.

Comment: `+` in second line should not be there.

Comment: This was my mistake in copying the code. I correct it , but still don't work

Answer (score -1):

```
    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:15000,4"+ );
```

, is not valid identifier that can be parsed. You can use " " or - instead.